# I am using XCODE 8. I tried installing appium 1.5 but I am unable to inspect elements. How can I use Appium with Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, appium

Xcode 8 with appium. Which appium version can be used with xcode 8.

Answer (score 1):

1. start appium server in terminal (current version is 1.6.3)
2. open appium ide (current version is 1.5.3 which is a bit outdated) **DO NOT click 'Launch'** - of course you should configure appium ide with build path and ios version in it
3. click inspector icon which looks like magnified glass
4. After a while(up to 60s) the inspector window will show up and allow you to inspect elements.